# ObjectFactory Class from Java Beans

Tags: jaxb

Can anyone please tell how to generate the ObjectFactory class from some Java beans ? Remember , I dont have the xsd and hence I cannot use JAXB for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The only class generation that JAXB (JSR-222) implementations do is from XML schema.  When starting from Java classes you just need to create a class and annotate it `@XmlRegistry`.  You will need to include this class in the array of classes used to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`.  The main reason for doing this is to leverage the `@XmlElementDecl` annotation to associated multiple root elements with a class.  Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Dear Blaise,
Can I have an example of this? I dont have an xsd. I just have Java bean classes.

Comment: @user1752663 - Here you go:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html